# WSO2 Test API across https with certificate having password

Tags: wso2

My API server runs over https with a custom certificate with the password. When I configure WSO2 API manager to use my API server, I am unable to provide the password. WIth postman things work but unable to make API manager work below is the error when I hit the test button.

```
[2018-04-16 17:58:15,904] ERROR - APIProviderHostObject Error occurred while connecting to backend : https://localhost:8443/ABC/rest/searches, reason : peer not authenticated
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(SSLSessionImpl.java:431)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.SSLProtocolSocketFactory.verifyHostName(SSLProtocolSocketFactory.java:276)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.SSLProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLProtocolSocketFactory.java:186)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.open(HttpConnection.java:707)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:387)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)
```

When I load the certificate, I get the below error

```
[2018-04-16 18:19:20,905] ERROR - CertificateMgtUtils Error loading certificate.
java.security.cert.CertificateParsingException: signed fields invalid
        at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.parse(X509CertImpl.java:1791)
        at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.<init>(X509CertImpl.java:195)
        at sun.security.provider.X509Factory.engineGenerateCertificate(X509Factory.java:102)
        at java.security.cert.CertificateFactory.generateCertificate(CertificateFactory.java:339)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.CertificateMgtUtils.addCertificateToTrustStore(CertificateMgtUtils.java:85)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.certificatemgt.CertificateManagerImpl.addCertificateToParentNode(CertificateManagerImpl.java:51)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl.addCertificate(APIProviderImpl.java:5070)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.UserAwareAPIProvider.addCertificate(UserAwareAPIProvider.java:43)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIProviderHostObject.jsFunction_uploadCertificate(APIProviderHostObject.java:5076)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:126)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.FunctionObject.call(FunctionObject.java:386)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callN(OptRuntime.java:52)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c3._c_anonymous_11(/publisher/modules/api/add.jag:254)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c3.call(/publisher/modules/api/add.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.applyOrCall(ScriptRuntime.java:2430)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.BaseFunction.execIdCall(BaseFunction.java:269)
```

Comment: we don't see how did you configure the client certificates.. you may have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42822397/wso2-api-manager-how-to-associate-a-client-certificate-to-backend-target-end   aren't you using different keystore (PKCS12/PFX instead of JKS)?

Comment: Just used JKS, used keytool for the certificate generation. But API Manager just asked for certificate and did not have the option to feed a password.